# Asp.net MVC - where query for multiple grids

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, where-clause

**Update 2**

Thanks to both Thomas Boby and Sam C. Both had good answers and perfect solution to this problem!

Here's my problem: I want my view to show four grids/columns with different textboxes. Example, when I create a Post Message I add a Priority level, 1-5, to it.

Now, I simply want to foreach every column where the "Priority = X", so the 1's shows on one column, and Posts with priority 2 shows on another column. Do you get it? Or am I really bad at explaining this.

Model class:

```
 public enum Priority
{
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Third = 3,
    Forth = 4,
    Fifth = 5,
}

public class Post
{
    public int postId { get; set; }

    public string postMsg { get; set; }

    public Priority priority { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I would want to do it like this:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.Posts) // Where Model.priority = 1
    {
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class=" panel panel-default">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.postMsg, new { @class = "panel-body" })
        </div>
      </div>
    }

 @foreach (var item in Model.Posts) // Where Model.priority = 2
    {
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class=" panel panel-default">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.postMsg, new { @class = "panel-body" })
        </div>
      </div>
    }
```

The thing is I don't know how to make the **"Where Model.priority = 1"** query. I'm not sure if I can make a query like that in the **foreach**?

**Update**

To make things much more simpler: I want to have a different "Select Where" query for different divs.

Comment: Yes, I can maybe fix that. But I have updated my question, to be easier to understand. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `System.Linq` something like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Posts.Where(x => x.priority == Priority.First))
{
...
}
```

Would loop over every item with a priority of 1.

Comment: I get "The name 'x' doesn't exist in the current context". :( That sounds though like the perfect solution.

Comment: You need to import System.Linq, and make sure you've got the right number of arguments for the Where. It'll complain until you do.

Comment: So I added using System.Linq, and the error I get now is: "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TimmApp.Models.Priority' and 'int'. Tried with string, and same error.

Comment: How about x => x.priority == Priority.First? Or TimmApp.Models.Priority.First, basically giving your enum.

Answer (score 1):

something like this ???

```
@foreach( var p in Enum.GetValues( typeof( Priority) ).Cast< Priority >().OrderBy(x=>(int)x) ) //sorted from first priority to fifth
{
    @foreach (var item in Model.Posts.Where(x=>x.Priority == p)) 
    {
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class=" panel panel-default">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.postMsg, new { @class = "panel-body" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Creative answer that automatically enumerates the possible where clause values in the outer loop.  Can you change the order you enumerate the enum (ie put most severe up top)?

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Thing is, both answers were correct, is there a way to mark both as correct?

Comment: @speckis  - nope, there can be only one "approved" answer.  Just choose the one that you found the **most helpful** to you.  Also, you can up or down vote as many answers as you want.  Click the arrows around the number, up if you found useful, down if you did not.  You can find some more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour. Oh and lastly, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Okey, that's the most logical approach I guess. Although I can't vote yet (need more reputation), but I had that idea. ;) 

And thank you!